# Which superhero first used the power of body shrinkage?

Tags: comics, history-of, powers

There are many superheroes who have the power to expand or contract their body size. In Marvel, we have Ant-Man and the Wasp, and in DC we have Atom.

Who was the first superhero to use the power of shrinking their body? In which comics is it mentioned first about this power?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I would suggest it was [Dollman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doll_Man) that debuted in [Feature comics #27 (1939)](https://www.comics.org/issue/581/)

[image]

Dollman was Darrel Dane, a chemist that discovered a way to shrink to the size of about 15 cm while keeping his original strength. He went on to be the first superhero publicized by  Quality Comics and had a long running series.
Dollman's powers were shown in his first adventure "Meet the Dollman" from his debut comic.

Comment: First appearance listed on included link states December 1941

Comment: That is one of dangers with linking to Wikipedia, some info might be wrong. Dollman was first introduced in  Feature comics #27 that was published in december 1939. After the character got popular Quality comic gave him his own title, The Dollman Quarterly. That comic was published 1941. Somehow Wikipedia seems to have got them mixed up. I will see if i can find a better source.

Comment: https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Feature_Comics_Vol_1_27 states the issue mentioned as being published December 1939 as you state

Answer (score 8):

**Update**: After a bit more research it appears Mighty Man didn't actually get his shrinking/growing powers until [issue 12 of Amazing-Man comics](https://readcomiconline.to/Comic/Amazing-Man-Comics/Issue-12?id=101633) (May 1940), before this he was just a giant. This is after the first appearance of Dollman as mentioned in another answer, but I'll leave the answer up, as I think it still adds to the conversation.

Maybe [Mighty Man](http://www.toonopedia.com/mightymn.htm) who first appeared in issue 5 of Centaur Publishing's [Amazing-Man Comics](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amazing-Man_(Centaur_Publications)) dated September 1939.

[image: Mighty Man big]

[image: Mighty Man small]

> Mighty Man was more than twice as tall as most people, and super-strong even for his size. Explorers of the American Southwest found him in the so-called "Valley of the Giants" (no relation), which had apparently been settled in the previous century, tho the settlers had all died, leaving the young giant the only survivor. Back in civilization, the future Mighty Man submitted to an experiment conducted by a Dr. Robert Hilldale, which brought him down to normal size, but also gave him the ability to shrink and grow at will.